# Add class to marker on click

Tags: javascript, google-maps, marker

On Google Maps I would like to add a class to the marker when clicking on it. 
I've searched the API but I can't find a solution. 
Do you have any leads?

Answer (score 0):

Use addListener:

```
var marker = google.maps.Marker({
    position: geolocation
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    // your code
});
```

Answer (score -2):

in fact, at this level I do not have to worry, but the concern is how to add a class marker.

thank you

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
    var curMarker = this;
    console.log( curMarker );
    curMarker.class = "myClasse"; // Exemple
});
```

butit does not work

Answer (score -2):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    marker.set("class", "className");
});
```

**u can also do this while creating a marker**

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
    map: map,
    class:'className'
    draggable: true
});
```

Comment: this class attribute is not supported, This doesnt do anything @mir-shakeel-hussain