# Google map round pin before putting on map

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, ionic-framework

Hi there I tried googling extensively but nothing seems to help.

This is my scenario:

1. Company logos are stored on an external domain/url (rectangular in shape).
2. Ionic application with a google map that places these logos as markers onto the map.

The markers look ugly and I want to make them round on the map.

I have found that if I add css to the entire page to say:

```
img { border-radius: 50%; }
```

Then it rounds the images but also rounds the map background.  I cannot specify the image url to style in css as each logo url will be different.  How can I achieve this via javascript alone or how can I assign a css class to each map pin?

EDIT:  Just to specify, I added such a generalized css styling because when I inspect the element then the map pin is part of the canvas and does not show up for me to inspect.  As mentioned above I would love to assign a css class to the pin so that I can target it directly.

Comment: Why are you setting that on the whole page and not _just_ the element you are trying to round?

Comment: @MattClark When I inspect the map and try access that element I can't, its part of the canvas so can't be accessed directly.  If I could add a css class to the pin as I add it then sure I would access it that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom markers, using your own images..

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-symbol-custom

And try here:

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=ZtNrt9vRt10

That should get you started..

Comment: Sorry but the first link is to create a marker based on a shape you draw.  I have an existing image that sits on a url that is used as a marker.  The second link doesn't help, I have no problem placing markers on the map, what I want to do is round the edges of the markers that get placed.

Comment: Okay, try this then: [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25367542/google-map-custom-marker-with-css-rounded-corner    The third answer in the link has an example of a square image being put in a rounded border. This puts the image onto  a circle. If it's only the edges you need rounding you should be able to use this example and use it with the first: [link] http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_borders.asp.

Answer (score 1):

@MikeCave's suggestion is great. I especially like this because high resolution screens will display markers better since Google Maps is constricting about multiple resolutions.

As the comment above, you need to be more specific if you're going to apply a general rule to all images like that. You can specify `iframe img` to get more specific since Google Maps puts the map inside an `iframe`. Better yet, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23381303/393219) to see about adding a class name to markers for better targeting.

Comment: Mikes answer does not help me, I already am able to place a marker, the icon used is a image sitting on a url, however I need to change each marker to have rounded edges regardless of how the image is shaped on the url.  Thats what my objective is.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this with the plugin MarkerWithLabel.  Then by placing the image in as a label under the marker I could hide the marker by defining the icon url as an empty string and then placing the image url into the label, the label then has a css class that I could manipulate via css.